# Python Selenium NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code :

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#bet').send_keys(2500)
time.sleep(2)
x = 0
while x < 100: 
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#start_game').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.tile:nth-child('+str(random.randint(1, 25))+')').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.tile:nth-child('+str(random.randint(1, 25))+')').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.tile:nth-child('+str(random.randint(1, 25))+')').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.cashout').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#start_game').click()
    time.sleep(10)
    x = x+1
```

Well my code play a minesweaper game with bitcoins. All works great he place the bet, start the game random click on 3 box. When he succed to click on 3 box and theres no bomb the cashout button appear but when the script click on a bomb the cashout button doesn't appear and i get nosuchelement.

I've tried to use:

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.cashout').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#start_game').click()
```

In case he click on bomb and cashout doesn't appear to start a new game... but it didn't work. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to switch to [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of hardcoded sleep calls.

Wait for `cashout` element to *become visible*, then click:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cashout"))
    )
    element.click()
except TimeoutException:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#start_game').click()
```

Comment: @Unchangeable well, I cannot help more at the moment. There is no way for me to reproduce what you see. I've just noted what could be the problem in your case hoping it helps.

Comment: at first line he start the game after click the elements and if there's no cashout he start a game and another game from first line.